# how to know which parameters to define in androidPlot xml layout file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, androidplot

I am going through quickstart for androidPlot. http://androidplot.com/docs/quickstart/ 
In the example simple_xy_plot_example.xml layout file is defined with parameters such as

```
androidPlot.titleWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/title_font_size"
            androidPlot.domainLabelWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/domain_label_font_size"
            androidPlot.rangeLabelWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/range_label_font_size"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.marginTop="20dp"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.marginLeft="15dp"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.marginBottom="25dp"
```

But where are these parameters defined? I mean how do I know to use titleWidget.labelPaint.textSize to define textSize?

Comment: Scroll down a bit more and you'll find it in the `res/values/dimens.xml` section.

Comment: I mean how do I define hierarchy path e.g.  ndroidPlot.graphWidget.marginLeft

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. You can find the XYPlot's documentation [here](http://androidplot.com/javadoc/0.6.0/com/androidplot/xy/XYPlot.html). You can find all its members there. You can't see its properties, but you'll find all its getters and setters. Just remove the get/set and you got your property.

Answer (score 0):

Define these variables in `res/values/dimens.xml` like this

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="title_font_size">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="domain_label_font_size">12dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="range_label_font_size">12dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="range_tick_label_font_size">12dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="domain_tick_label_font_size">12dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="legend_text_font_size">12dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Where `domain_label_font_size` is the value you want to define.